# Ошибка при добавлении в множество

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Выдает такую ошибку при добавлении мужских имен после женских или наоборот:

> File "C:.../GUI.py", line 60, in add_to_list_men
>
> self.B.add(self.men[event.widget.curselection()[0]])
>
> IndexError: tuple index out of range

Код:

```
from tkinter import *
import pickle
import random
import copy

class Lab2:
    A = set()
    B = set()

    def student(self, n = 19, g = 71):
        self.slave = Toplevel(self.root)
        self.slave.title('Student')
        self.slave.focus_set()
        self.slave.minsize(300, 100)
        self.slave.maxsize(300, 100)
        self.slave.wm_geometry("+600+250")
        Label(self.slave, text='Севрук Артем\n'
                               'група ІВ-71\n'
                               'варіант {}'.format((n+g % 60) % 30+1),
              justify=LEFT, font="Arial 17 bold").pack(fill='both')

    def mainwindow(self):
        self.root = Tk()
        self.root.title('Window1')
        self.root.minsize(500, 200)
        self.root.maxsize(500, 200)
        self.root.wm_geometry("+500+200")

        Label(self.root, text='Лабораторна робота №2\n'
                              '«Бінарні відношення та їх основні властивості,\n'
                              ' операції над відношеннями»\n', font="Arial 16 bold").grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=4)
        Button(self.root, text='Window2', font="Arial 12", command=self.window2).grid(row=1, column=0)
        #Button(self.root, text='Window3', font="Arial 12", #command=self.window3).grid(row=2, column=0)
       # Button(self.root, text='Window4', font="Arial 12", #command=self.window4).grid(row=3, column=0)

        Button(self.root, text='Студент', font='Arial 14', height=2, width=10,
               command=self.student).grid(column=2, row=1, sticky=E, rowspan=2)
        self.root.mainloop()

    def window2(self):
        global A, B
        self.A = set()
        self.B = set()

        self.slave2 = Toplevel(self.root)
        self.slave2.title('Window2')
        self.slave2.focus_set()

        def add_to_list_women(event):
            if var.get() == 0:
                self.A.add(self.women[event.widget.curselection()[0]])
            if var.get() == 1:
                self.B.add(self.women[event.widget.curselection()[0]])
            lb['text'] = 'A = {}\nB = {}\n'.format(self.A, self.B)

        def add_to_list_men(event):
            if var.get() == 0:
                self.A.add(self.men[event.widget.curselection()[0]])
            if var.get() == 1:
                self.B.add(self.men[event.widget.curselection()[0]])
            lb['text'] = 'A = {}\nB = {}\n'.format(self.A, self.B)

        def clean_lists():
            self.A = set()
            self.B = set()
            lb['text'] = 'A = {}\nB = {}\n'.format(self.A, self.B)

        def save_to_file():
            self.f = open('МножиниАВ.txt', 'wb')
            pickle.dump(self.A, self.f)
            pickle.dump(self.B, self.f)
            self.f.close()
            but['text'] = 'Збережено'
            but['state'] = DISABLED

        def show_from_file():
            self.show = Toplevel(self.slave2)
            self.show.title('Window2/Show_sets')
            self.show.focus_set()
            self.show.minsize(300, 100)
            self.f = open('МножиниАВ.txt', 'rb')
            Label(self.show, text='A={}\n'
                                  'B={}'.format(pickle.load(self.f), pickle.load(self.f)), font='Arial 14', justify=LEFT)\
                .pack(fill=BOTH)
            self.f.close()

        Label(self.slave2, text='Задайте множини А та В', font='Arial 16 bold').grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=4)

        var = IntVar()
        var.set(0)
        rad0 = Radiobutton(self.slave2, text="Множина A", font='Arial 12 bold', variable=var, value=0)
        rad1 = Radiobutton(self.slave2, text="Множина B", font='Arial 12 bold', variable=var, value=1)
        rad0.grid(column=0, row=1, sticky=W)
        rad1.grid(column=0, row=2, sticky=W)

        lf1 = LabelFrame(self.slave2, text="Жіночі імена", font='Arial 12')
        lf1.grid(row=3, column=0, columnspan=2)

        self.women = ['Настя', 'Маша', 'Аня', 'Катя', 'Юля', 'Даша', 'Оля', 'Люда']
        listbox1 = Listbox(lf1, selectmode=EXTENDED, font='Arial 14')
        for i in self.women:
            listbox1.insert(END, i)
        listbox1.bind("<<ListboxSelect>>", add_to_list_women)
        listbox1.grid(row=3, column=0)

        scr1 = Scrollbar(lf1, command=listbox1.yview)
        listbox1.configure(yscrollcommand=scr1.set)
        scr1.grid(row=3, column=1, sticky=W, ipady=90)

        lf2 = LabelFrame(self.slave2, text="Чоловічі імена", font='Arial 12')
        lf2.grid(row=3, column=2, columnspan=2)

        self.men = ['Андрій', 'Антон', 'Денис', 'Богдан', 'Віталій', 'Віктор', 'Костя', 'Сергій', 'Вова']
        listbox2 = Listbox(lf2, selectmode=EXTENDED, font='Arial 14')
        for i in self.men:
            listbox2.insert(END, i)
        listbox2.bind("<<ListboxSelect>>", add_to_list_men)
        listbox2.grid(row=3, column=2)

        scr2 = Scrollbar(lf2, command=listbox2.yview)
        listbox2.configure(yscrollcommand=scr2.set)
        scr2.grid(row=3, column=3, sticky=W, ipady=90)

        Button(self.slave2, text='Очистити множини', font='Arial 12', command=clean_lists)\
            .grid(row=4, column=0, columnspan=2)

        but = Button(self.slave2, text='Зберегти в файл', font='Arial 12', command=save_to_file)
        but.grid(row=4, column=2, columnspan=2)

        Button(self.slave2, text='Показати з файлу', font='Arial 12', command=show_from_file)\
            .grid(row=5, column=2, columnspan=2)

        lf3 = LabelFrame(self.slave2, text='Задані множини', font='Arial 12', )
        lf3.grid(row=6, column=0, columnspan=5, sticky=W)
        lb = Label(lf3, text='A = {}\n'
                             'B = {}\n'.format(self.A, self.B), font='Arial 14', justify=LEFT)
        lb.grid(row=6, column=0, columnspan=5, sticky=W)
        A=self.A ; B=self.B

lab = Lab2()
lab.mainwindow()
```

Comment: Перед использованием `event.widget.curselection()[0]` я бы проверил что может вернуть `curselection()`, скорее всего там пусто

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте проверку [`curselection()`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/800758/%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%B2-%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE#comment1264893_800758) до в добавление данных в `lb`

```
....
def add_to_list_women(event):
    if event.widget.curselection():
        if var.get() == 0:
            self.A.add(self.women[event.widget.curselection()[0]])
        if var.get() == 1:
            self.B.add(self.women[event.widget.curselection()[0]])
        lb['text'] = 'A = {}\nB = {}\n'.format(self.A, self.B)
    else:
        print('None')


def add_to_list_men(event):
    if event.widget.curselection():
        if var.get() == 0:
            self.A.add(self.men[event.widget.curselection()[0]])
        if var.get() == 1:
            self.B.add(self.men[event.widget.curselection()[0]])
        lb['text'] = 'A = {}\nB = {}\n'.format(self.A, self.B)
....
```